# Node js Stream file without saving to memory

Tags: node.js, express, busboy, nodejs-stream

I am building an API that needs to accept file uploads. So a user can `POST` a file to an endpoint, the file will be sent to a virus scan, then if it's clean will be sent to storage (probably S3). So far I have achieved this with one issue: The files are temporarily saved in the applications file system. I need to design an app that doesn't store things in memory. Here is my currently working code:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bb = require('express-busboy');

const app = express();

// Busboy modules extends the express app to handle incoming files
bb.extend(app, {
    upload: true,
    path: './tmp'
});
```

**Routes.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fileManagementService = require('./file-management-service')();

router
.route('/:fileId')
.post(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const {fileId} = req.params;
        const {files} = req;
        const response = await fileManagementService.postFile(files, fileId);

        res.status(201).json(response);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
})
```

**file-management-service.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');

function createUploader() {
    // POST /:fileId
    async function postFile(data, fileId) {
        const {file} = data.file;
        const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        const scanOutput = await scanFile(fileStream); // Function scans file for viruses
        const status = scanOutput.status === 'OK';
        let upload = 'NOT UPLOADED';
        if (status) {
            upload = await postS3Object({file}); // Some function that sends the file to S3 or other storage
        }
        fs.unlinkSync(file);
        return {
            fileId,
            scanned: scanOutput,
            upload 
        };
    }

    return Object.freeze({
        postFile
    });
}

module.exports = createUploader;
```

As mentioned, the above works as expected, the file is sent to be scanned, then sent to an S3 bucket before returning a response to the poster to that effect. However my implementation of express-busboy is storing the file in the `./tmp` folder, then I'm converting this into a readable stream using `fs.createReadStream(filePath);` before sending it to the AV and again in the function that sends the file to S3.

This API is being hosted in a kubernetes cluster and I need to avoid creating states. How can I achieve the above without actually saving the file? I'm guessing busboy receives this file as some sort of stream, so without sounding dense, can it not just remain a stream and be piped through these functions to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use busboy at a bit lower level and get access to it's translated readstream.  Here's an example from [the busboy doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) that can be adapted for your situation:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), path.basename(fieldname));
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
      res.end("That's all folks!");
    });
    return req.pipe(busboy);
  }
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.end();
}).listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Listening for requests');
});
```

The key part is this which I've annotated:

```
    // create a new busboy instance on each incoming request that has files with it
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

    // register for the file event
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      // at this point the file argument is a readstream for the data of an uploaded file
      // you can do whatever you want with this readstream such as
      // feed it directly to your anti-virus 

      // this example code saves it to a tempfile
      // you would replace this with code that sends the stream to your anti-virus
      var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), path.basename(fieldname));
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    });

    // this recognizes the end of the upload stream and sends 
    // whatever you want the final http response to be
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
      res.end("That's all folks!");
    });

    // this gets busboy started, feeding the incoming request to busboy
    // so it can start reading it and parsing it and will eventually trigger
    // one or more "file" events
    return req.pipe(busboy);
```

When you've identified an incoming request that you want to do this custom busboy operation in, you create an instance of Busboy, pass it the headers and register for the `file` event.  That file event gives you a new `file` readstream that is the converted file as a readstream.  You could then pipe that stream directly to your anti-virus without ever going through the file system.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had actually found that `busboy` example in the hours of googling I'd done before posting this question, but failed to make it work. Your annotations helped a lot!